# WebApi Routing: is it a good idea to have RouteAtrribute for each api service?

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, routes

I normally removed the global webapi routing and add attribute routing for each api service. Since the service number is getting bigger, i am a bit concern about the performance. Anybody has any suggestion on it?

from what i can see

Pros: less security concerns

Cons: performance?

Comment: If service number gets changing how come you can use them as global one ?..

Comment: global routing like "{controller}/{action}", basically i have removed this routing for security concern.